# Will cupy support cython( eg. buffered index)?

Tags: cython, chainer, cupy

I have implement myself defined a chainer Link, but because it is too slow.
I have implemented cython CPU version of my code. But I want to further boost speed via GPU. So I test the following code , but it failed:

```
%%cython

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
import cupy as cp
cimport cupy as cp
cdef class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    cdef cp_test(self, cp.ndarray[cp.float_t, ndim=2] arr):
        return cp.sum(arr)

a = A()
arr = cp.arange(100).reshape(20,50)
print(a.cp_test(arr))
```

reporting:

```
    cdef cp_test(self, cp.ndarray[cp.float_t, ndim=2] arr):
                      ^
------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\.ipython\cython\_cython_magic_d4940a274af88f0257c368b8a5d0e3f5.pyx:13:23: 'ndarray' is not a type identifier
```

Comment: How to use cython and cupy together ? what is the best practice?

Comment: Your error message is just because you've typed `cp` instead of `np`. I'm voting to close as a typo

Comment: No , I am not talking about numpy, but cupy , a chainer group released CUDA supported GPU version of numpy, I want to know if it can work with cython.

Comment: Don't close this issue

Comment: OK - I see what you mean. Cython can compile the vast majority of Python code (so it will work) but you probably can't specify types and probably won't get much speedup.

Comment: I mean if I use buffered index np.ndarray just like :  np.ndarray[np.float_t, ndim=2] arr, How to define this function argument in cupy? Is this Cython official code doing this , not python-numpy group 's source code doing this? So is it possible to use buffered index to speed up in cython.

Comment: What do you mean, I don't understand , really need help

Comment: I would not expect Cython to help much. The real work will be done on the GPU, which CuPy arranges and not Cython. Just write the code in Python first.

Comment: Because my program is multiple small matrix computation inside a big for-loop, because the next matrix computation depends on previous compute result, so it cannot combine to one big matrix computation, I have already implemented it in numpy + cython, which have already boost speed compared to original python program. I want to further boost speed via GPU, so I need cupy to do that. because for loop exists , Do you think cython won't help? Can small matrix computation GPU boost?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but CuPy does not provide cython interface currently (I am one of CuPy developers).
The feature request is open at https://github.com/cupy/cupy/issues/130.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17899160)

Comment: The essential parts of answer is written as comments as "CuPy does not provide cython interface currently". The link was just for the feature request on the issue tracker.